# Getting data wtith Ajax (Placing inside div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to add my data into a div, and its not working. The php is fine but I need a fine eye to see if they can spot any errors or can suggest any work arounds to help figure out why its not working.

I've tried to fix it for the past 5 hours or so and its racking my brains.

The user comments on a status like post and its suppose to add it to the div. Just like my main status does. The ajax for the main status is almost identical to the comment ajax below..yet the comment ahax isn't playing nice and is not inserting any data at all.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#mycommentform").submit(function() {
        var streamidcontent = $('#streamidcontent').val();
        var contents = $(this).children('#contents').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_add.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { streamidcontent: streamidcontent, contents: contents}, 
            success: function(data){  
                $('#containerid').html('<div class="stream_comment_holder" style="display:none;"
                id="comment_holder_'+data['comment_streamitem']+'"><div
                id="comment_list_'+data['comment_streamitem']+'"><div
                id="tgy"></div><div class="stream_comment"
                id="comment_'+data['comment_id']+'" style="margin-top:0px;"><table
                width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img
                class="stream_profileimage"
                style="border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;" border=\"0\"
                src=\"imgs/cropped'+data['id']+'.jpg\"
                onerror="this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"" width=\"40\"
                height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left><a
                href="/profile.php?username='+data['username']+'">'+data['first']+'</a><div
                class="commentholder">'+data['first']+'</div><br/><div
                id="commentactivitycontainer"></div></div></table></div></div><div
                class="form"><form id="mycommentform" method="POST" 
                class="form_statusinput"><input type="hidden"  name="streamidcontent"
                id="streamidcontent" value="'+data['comment_streamitem']+'"><input
                type="text" name"contents" id="contents" placeholder="Say something"
                autocomplete="off"><input type="submit" id="button"
                value="Feed"></form></div><div class="stream_comment_holder"
                style="display:;"><div class="like_name"><b><a
                href="profile.php?username='+data['username']+'">You Like
                This</a></b></div></div>');
            }
        });
        return false
    });
});
</script>
```

ERROR FOUND

```
success: function (data) {
    alert("SUCCESS!!!");
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}

OK
200
SyntaxError.JSONparse:Unexpectedcharacter
```

JSON

```
$json = array();
$check = "SELECT comment_id, comment_datetime, comment_streamitem FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_streamitem=".$_POST['streamidcontent']."";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
$json['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
$json['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];
mysqli_free_result($check1);

$check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($check1);
$json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
$json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
$json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
$json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
$json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];
mysqli_free_result($check1);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: That's better, but it's invalid syntax.  (newliens in string literals) Just put in the actual code on your site.  (if your actual code is not indented correctly, fix that first)

Comment: Yes. Its fine on my site. :) No spaces allowed etc..etc.

Comment: So if you replace the `$('#containerid').html('...')` with `console.log(data)` what do you get?

Comment: I would also try to separate the success function call into its own separate function. Not sure why but sometimes that made the difference for me.

Comment: Nothing at all . I don't get anything. 

How would I go about that @aug?

Comment: so in your `success : function(data) {` instead put something like `success: successCall` and then write a `function successCall(data) {`. I feel sometimes the code tries to immediately run the success function if you write it immediately but usually that shouldn't be the case. You can try it though.

Comment: _"Nothing at all"_ - Was that in response to my comment? A `console.log()` statement doesn't actually log anything? If your sucess function isn't getting called then all that html is just a distraction at this point - I'd remove that and just get a simple `alert(data)` working first, then add back in the real functionality. Are you sure the PHP page is actually getting hit? @aug - that should make no difference.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not putting it in the right place. But the comment and steamid is both being sent into the database and I'm getting back the reesponse in firebug. So.. :/

Comment: OK, so yes, your PHP works. But if a simple `success : function(data) { alert(data); }` doesn't do anything try adding an error handler and see if it gets called: `error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }` (or instead of the alert perhaps `console.log(errorThrown)`, etc).

Comment: I'm not familiar with console.log if I'm honest. Can I use this with Firebug to determine any errors?

Comment: Firebug provides a "console" - you just have to turn that on, though I'm not sure exactly how to do that because I use Chrome's console for most of my debugging rather than Firebug. Anyway, `console.log("some text")` will log `"some text"` to that console: it's a handy way to check the value of various variables without having lots of `alert()` statements everywhere. It's well worth learning to use. Meanwhile though, try an error handler with a simple alert as per my previous comment.

Comment: Edited the question with the error, maybe it will make more sense to someone.

Comment: @dave try copying a valid JSON string from somewhere and edit your comments .php to send that valid JSON as response, so you can check if the problem is in json syntax.

Comment: Still throws the same Unexpectedcharacter message even with the JSON that is fine.

Comment: @sabithpocker So where is this  Unexpectedcharacter going to be? In the actual ajax or in the PHP page?

Comment: Can you show the JSON in question? And how you're echoing it out from your PHP page?

Comment: @nnnnnn Added it to the question. Sorry. Had to go to bed. It was knocking on 3am here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using some sort of templating system to do all the hard work assembling your content.

Take a look into [Create a makeshift Javascript templating](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-makeshift-javascript-templating-solution/) or [John Resig's](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) solution.

Building that string of mark-up inside `html()` is a little crude.

You also have an inline style of display:none on the first `div`, so you won't see it.

Have you tried stripping the function down just to see if anything gets populated

```
success: function(data){  
   $('#containerid').html('blurb');
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that method. With just my username. Still nothing. Trying some suggestions made.

Comment: is that success function actually getting called? insert an alert('Passed') in the success function

or 

add an error handler

success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }

Comment: When I put success in..No popup. When I put in error it shows popup. Yet it shows in firebug those items being sent over to php and returns back all the values I ask to grab.

Comment: try this

     error: function(xhr, textStatus){
                alert('request failed->'+textStatus);
            }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but where you're trying to embed quotation marks inside the html attributes that you're creating, e.g.:

```
'onerror="this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\""'
```

It will produce this invalid string:

```
onerror="this.src="img/no_profile_img.jpeg""
```

You should embed single quotes instead, like this:

```
'onerror="this.src=\'img/no_profile_img.jpeg\'"'
```

Which would produce:

```
onerror="this.src='img/no_profile_img.jpeg'"
```

Also, on about the sixth last line you have an attribute missing an `=` sign:

```
name"contents"
```

And the outer-most div you are inserting has `style="display:none;"`.

Comment: Tried all your suggestions..still nothing.

Comment: From the comments above you've got more fundamental problems to solve first. Once you can get your success handler to fire _then_ you'll need to apply the fixes from my answer.